# Show that there exists $w \in \mathbb C$ such that $a w^2 - w +1 =0$ and $| w - 1| \leq 1$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gershgorin-sets

> $\forall a \in \mathbb{C}$ prove that there exists $w \in \mathbb{C}$ such that
> $$aw^2 - w + 1 = 0$$
> $$|w - 1| ≤ 1$$

My attempt was to use the [Gershgorin circle Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) on a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{2 \times 2}$ such that $p_A(z) = az^2 - z + 1$

Then the solutions of the equation

$$az^2 - z + 1 = 0$$

Would be the eigenvalues of $A$

unfortunately I haven't managed to complete this proof.

Comment: Seems like you might want something simpler, like first start with the quadratic formula.

Comment: Hint: $\;(w_1-1)(w_2-1) = \dots$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I finally managed to prove it using the quadratic formula. I showed that $|w_1 - 1| * |w_2 - 1| = 1$ where $w_1$ and $w_2$ are the solutions of $az^2 - z + 1 = 0$. Btw I wonder if there's a way to prove it using Gershgorin circle theorem

Comment: @Paul: Well, if you have a proof, feel free to answer your own question.

Comment: The substitution $w := 1 + u$ will simplify your calculations.

Comment: @Dan I think the proof would be too short to be an answer. By using the [quadratic formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) and the well known formula $(A + B)(A - B) = A^2 - B^2$ it's really easy to set that $(w_1 - 1)(w_2 - 1) = 1$, where $w_1$ and $w_2$ are the solutions of $az^2 - z + 1 = 0$. Therefore $|w_1 - 1| \cdot |w_2 - 1| = 1$ so either $|w_1 - 1| \leq 1$ or $|w_2 - 1| \leq 1$ (otherwise we would have $|w_1 - 1| \cdot |w_2 - 1| > 1$ ) which completes the proof.

Comment: @Paul All you need for that is [Vieta's relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) $\,w_1+w_2=w_1w_2=1/a\,$.

Comment: @Paul "would be too short to be an answer": for answers, the shorter the better.